# Solving a wave equation (PDE)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

A semi-infinite string with one end fixed at the origin, is strectched along the positive half of the $x$ axis and released at rest from a position $y=f(x)$ $(x\geq 0)$. Derieve the expression

$$y(x,t)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty} \cos\alpha(at) \sin\alpha(x)\int_{0}^{\infty} f(s)\sin\alpha(s) \,\mathrm ds\,\mathrm da$$

for the tranverse displacement. Let $F(x)(-\infty<x<\infty)$ denote the odd extention of $f(x)$ and show how this result reduces to

$$y(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[F(x+at)+F(x-at)$$

What i tried

The expression

$$y(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[F(x+at)+F(x-at)$$

which i know immediately as the De-Alembert solution of the wave equation

My boundary conditions are

$$u_{t}(x,t)=ku_{xx}(x,t)$$

$$u(t,0)=0$$

$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$
Is my boundary conditions correct?

THen using seperation of variables, i got

$$X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0$$

$$X(0)=0$$

and

$$T'(t)+\lambda kT(t)=0$$

The eigenvalues are

$$\lambda=\alpha^2$$

Eigenvectors are
$$T(t)=\exp(-\alpha^2 kt)$$

$$u(x,t)=\int_{0}^\infty \beta(\alpha)\exp(-\alpha^2 kt)\sin(\alpha (ax) da$$
Im not sure of how to continue from here. Could anyone explain every step of the problem for me.Thanks

Comment: You are wanting to solve the wave equation, but you're solving the heat equation.

Comment: Okay Thanks. Would u  be able to explain how to go about solving this problem?

Comment: Look up the wave equation, and edit your question with the correct wave equation. Also, where you write $\alpha(s)$ do you mean some function named $\alpha$, or do you multiply $\alpha s$?